# Font Browser on OSX?

Tags: font

myfonts.com has a create feature where we can choose sample text and selected size while browsing hundreds of fonts. This makes my life much easier when I need to decide which font to use in my design. I like to know if there is a desktop application that does the same thing (either system app or App Store apps that runs on OSX).

For those who don't know what I ask, I did a screen shot to demonstrate what I meant by 'where we can choose sample text and selected size while browsing hundreds of fonts'.

[image]

Comment: Typo in title: front instead of font.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really a desktop OS X app, but might still be useful:

http://wordmark.it/

List all your fonts, using the text/size you specify. Allows filtering etc.

Comment: You are the man.

Comment: Note that this requires Flash to work.

Answer (score 5):

Font Book in your Applications folder. Comes preinstalled with Mac OS X. Choose Custom (under the "View" option on screen top menu bar) and then type the text you want to preview. Then you can cycle through your installed fonts using the up/down arrow keys and the preview will display your custom text in the highlighted font.

[image]

Comment: Wow Sam this is really cool! I am going to give you a vote up. However this is not exactly I what I was looking for because I still need to cycle through hundreds of fonts instead of simply scrolling down like on myfonts.com.

Comment: I believe if you select multiple fonts in the list it will show them in rows. I might be thinking of Suitcase though.

Comment: it deos allow for multi selection but if for example you select all the fonts it will limit the number it actually shows.